# Add record to a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, relationship

I have two models, users and promotions. The idea is that a promotion can have many users, and a user can have many promotions.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :promotions
end

class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I also have a promotions_users table/model, with no id of its own.  It references user_id and promotions_id

```
class PromotionsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

So, how do I add a user to a promotion?  I've tried something like this:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
promotion = Promotion.find(params[:promo_id])
promo = user.promotions.new(promo)
```

This results in the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys!' for #<Promotion:0x10514d420>
```

If I try this line instead:
promo= user.promotions.new(promo.id)

I get this error:

```
TypeError: can't dup Fixnum
```

I'm sure that there is a very easy solution to my problem, and I'm just not searching for the solution the right way.

Answer (score 53):

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
promotion = Promotion.find(params[:promo_id])
user.promotions << promotion
```

`user.promotions` is an array of the promotions tied to the user.

See the [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) for all the different functions you have available.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I figured I was overcomplicating things.

Comment: does << also save the association?

Comment: @Coolguy123 yes, `collection<<(object, …)` is an alias of  collection.push and collection.concat. This instantly fires update sql without waiting for the save or update call on the parent object.

Answer (score 11):

You can do just

```
User.promotions = promotion #notice that this will delete any existing promotions
```

or

```
User.promotions << promotion
```

You can read about `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship [here](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001092).

Comment: Be careful with `User.promotions = promotion` as that will delete any existing and add the one passed in.

Comment: j., i haven't seen http://railsapi.com. This is awesome! So much better than http://api.rubyonrails.org.

Comment: @Tony: Yes, I know that :] Tks.

Comment: pretty sure you mean `user.promotions` not `User.promotions`. The association's methods are on an instance not the class.

Answer (score 10):

This is also useful

```
User.promotion.build(attr = {})
```

so, promotion object saves, when you save User object.

And this is

```
User.promotion.create(attr = {})
```

create promotion you not need to save it or User model

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a User to a Promotion using a prototypical PromotionsController CRUD setup and you're *not* using Rails form helpers, you can format the params as:

```
params = {id: 1, promotion: { id: 1, user_ids: [2] }}
```

This allows you to keep the controller slim, e.g., you don't have to add anything special to the `update` method.

```
class PromotionsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    promotion.update(promotion_params)

    # simplified error handling
    if promotion.errors.none?
      render json: {message: 'Success'}, status: :ok
    else
      render json: post.errors.full_messages, status: :bad_request
    end
  end

  private

  def promotions_params
    params.require(:promotion).permit!
  end

  def promotion
    @promotion ||= Promotion.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

The result would be:

```
irb(main)> Promotion.find(1).users
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 2 ...>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

For all those in the current times, Rails does have built-in functions that are like simpler associations.

For building (i.e. Promotion.new), you can use

```ruby
user.promotions.build(promotion_attributes)
```

For creating it's the same

```ruby
user.promotions.create(promotion_attributes)
```

Just wanted to give a more familiar option. It's outline in the [apidoc](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) The other answers work as well.