# Ruby on Rails has_and_belongs_to_many association issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, associations

so basically I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user
end
```

and my migration was:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTablePostsUsers posts users
```

But in my console if I type:

```
@post = Post.where(:id => User.find_by_email("me@mail.com").post_ids).last
```

but I get nil instead

I checked in the terminal:

```
Post.last.user_ids
```

and:

```
User.last.post_ids
```

both of them returned empty

Comment: What are you doing to create the `PostUser` entry in the database?

Comment: forgot about that

Comment: Rails will only automatically create a join row if you create the records from one end. eg `Post.last.users.create`. I'm a bit unsure if you don't just have the wrong type of association. What is the actual use case?

Comment: @Okomikeruko since the association is `has_and_belongs_to_many` there is no  `PostUser` model. Rather just rows in the `users_posts` join table.

Comment: Could you also post the contents of the migration that was generated? There is no intermediate model here, perhaps your join table wasn't created correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered before here: [Add record to a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740070/add-record-to-a-has-and-belongs-to-many-relationship).

Basically, you need to assign values to one another.

```
post = Post.find(x)
user = User.last
user.posts << post
```

They're returning empty because they are empty and need their values to be assigned.